# Handling ResultProxy objects

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query my table named "books" and using a raw sql to get a title of the book. Currently, the table hase 5 columns: id, isbn, title, author, p_year. The query is returning me a ResultProxy object and I cannot figure out a way to extract the title from it

```py
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        results = db.engine.execute("""
            select * from books where title like '%% + form.input.data + %%'
        """)
        print(list(results))
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)
```

Am I using the query correctly actually? I was in a course and course requiements specifically dictates that I should use raw SQL. BTW, I am using SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy)? If so, you could try something like this:

```
results = results.fetchall()

for result in results:
 ...
```

Comment: I already tried it. It is returning an error saying that it is not iterable

Comment: What is returned by results.fetchall() ? It may just be a single row, causing the iterable error.

Comment: it is returning thiswhen I run your code: TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. If you want to query the database table for the match of the user input using SQLAlchemy, do this:

```py
        form = SearchForm()
        results = Book.query.filter(Book.title.ilike('%%' + form.input.data + '%')).all()
        for result in results:
            print(f"{result.title}, {result.author}, {result.p_year}")
```

Here, (Book) is the table name from your models, the first line returns a list object and you can loop through one by one. (title, author, p_year) are the column names in my table, I am using a form to create a searchbar